# JQuery auto handle multiple buttons click

Tags: jquery

I have many buttons each one is specified by its id . i would like to handler an automatic clik for these buttons when  another button with specified class is clicked . below is console log of these buttons .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.all-product-cart').click(function() {

    $('button.btn.an_productattributes-add-to-cart-btn.js-an_productattributes-add-to-cart').each(function() {
        var likeElement = $(this);
        likeElement.css("background-color", "yellow");

    });

});
});
```

[image]

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do/achieve, but looks like you can do `$('.all-products').not(this).click()` - which is a bad idea as it stands because you've said you want all the other buttons clicked each time one is clicked ... so clicking one will click all the others, which each in turn will click *all the others* etc = a huge mass of click events swamping your browser.

Comment: Sounds like you want to move the "click all" feature into a separate function that doesn't run the click events of all the others but does whatever you want to happen on click of *any*.

Comment: Can you describe your problem clearer?  What are you trying to achieve?  Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: for example when clicking  $('.all-product-cart') ,   i have tried to change background color for each sub buttons :  likeElement.css("background-color", "yellow") , it works well .
but trigger('click')  on sub buttons doesn't work .

Comment: Do you mean: "when another button with a **different** class is clicked" - that makes more sense

Comment: i have edited post ; there are sub buttons with  class     $('button.btn.an_productattributes-add-to-cart-btn.js-an_productattributes-add-to-cart') , i would like to trigger click on these buttons instead of changing background color (wich is a sample )

Comment: Can you update your question to include a *snippet* that demonstrates the problem your having?  While it does make more sense now, there doesn't seem to be an immediate problem with what you're trying to do, so might be the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve. Try to use following code for handling click events. Check if it works.

```
$(document).on('click','.all-product-cart',function() {
 //your code
});
```